# Substitution for display='table-cell' in IE 7

Tags: javascript, html, css

`document.getElementById(id).style.display ='table-cell'`. This gives error message in IE, this is IE bug or any other solutions please give any other solutions.

IE7 doesn't support this property.

this is my coding. Even Firefox and Chrome are accepted. My problem is IE. Please friends give solution...

```
var cont2 = document.createElement('div');
cont2.style.display = "table-cell";
cont2.style.verticalAlign = "middle";
cont2.style.lineHeight = 100+"%";
cont2.style.padding = 10+"px";
cont2.appendChild(body);
```

Comment: Which version of IE are you targetting?

Comment: "how to replace ie error" -> Replace IE

Comment: @Marcel - what makes you think this is for tabular data? Looks to me like the OP just wants td style vertical align behaviour on a div.

Comment: @Alohci: yeah, you're right. Jeny: BTW, you can simply replace `100+"%"` with `"100%"` and `10+"px"` with `"10px"`.

Answer (score 1):

[In short IE7 doesn't support these display values](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html), they post-date IE7.

Without knowing your layout, I don't know exactly the solution you're after, but if you want to support IE7, you can't use `display: table-cell;`, they are mutually exclusive.  Is it possible to change your layout to use another format, or [a conditional stylesheet for IE perhaps](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/)?

Answer (score 0):

If the only browser it's not working in is IE, then yes, it's likely a bug in IE. (At least old versions of) IE have never supported the table display properties properly.